# Permanently delete some categories in a .desktop file

Tags: linux, .desktop

I use to edit a .desktop file to remove some categories so that a program appears in only one menu item. But if I reinstall the package (apt install --reinstall ...) the editing ("Categories=" field) is lost. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: cp the desktop file to `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` and make the changes there.

Comment: Ok, it works, but only for the current user. If I add a new one, I should copy the modified .desktop files to the new .local dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay found another way; this is for all users.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/applications/
```

and move your desktop file there. I made an own starter for mpv (with some options for playing DVD's).

When I put a dvd in my dvd drive I get following image,[image: mpv-dvd]

mpv-dvd is my own starter. I remembered one's uppon a time it was the way to make starter on your own. It seems it is still respected. It is also in my application start menu. (tested in lxqt ubuntu jammy)

Comment: Perfect; it works for me too. Thanks. I have Debian 11.